# Add exception to a boolean method

Tags: java

I have an equals method to compare some attributes, this is how it looks:

```
public boolean Complementos(COSTOS obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;

    if (obj == null)
        return false;

    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    COSTOS other = (COSTOS) obj;
    if (NumeroParte == null) {
        if (other.NumeroParte != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!NumeroParte.equals(other.NumeroParte))
        return false;

    if (descripcion == null) {
        if (other.descripcion != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!descripcion.equals(other.descripcion))
        return false;

    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(monto) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.monto))
        return false;

    if (referencia != other.referencia)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

But besides to see if the attributes are equals, i want to return a value from "compareToIgnoreCase" from the attributes "-1, 0, 1" and i'm not allow to do it because of the method that is boolean and i tried to make it "int" but that would just mark as error my "return false/true", so... could i use an exception? if i could... how could i implemented?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to return both boolean and int? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: 1. never use exceptions for "normal" flow, 2. if your result type does not allow what you want to return, then something is off and 3. keep separate things separate, so here in separate methods.

Comment: While not relevant to your question, you should really use more braces in your conditional code. It’s obviously not necessary for the *compiler* to understand your code, but it would definitely help *people*. Just because you don’t *need* to use braces for a single-line body, doesn’t mean you *shouldn’t*!

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use an exception to convey this, but you definitely shouldn't.  Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances and shouldn't be used to control the flow of your application.

Generally speaking, if you have a method that needs to return more than one output then you should split it into multiple methods.  This makes your code more reusable and your APIs less confusing.

In the rare case where you can't do this, you can return an object representing the result of the method.  For example:

```
@Transactional
public LoginResponse login(String username, char[] password);
```